# Como detectar quando o textarea possui mais de uma linha?

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

Estou fazendo um chat, e me deparei com o seguinte problema, o meu `textarea` ao quebrar uma linha, seja ao usuario pressionar enter ou não ter espaço suficiente e saltar para a proxima linha, meu `textearea` não aumenta de tamanho quando chega ao limite, que nem acontece em alguns chat (Como o discord ...). Então pensei o seguinte, coloco meu `textarea` em uma tamanho fixo, quando tiver outra linha, aumento meu `textarea` em 20 pixels.

Porem me deparei com este problema, como eu detectar qts linhas meu `textarea` está ocupando em texto?

Só lembrando que quem for digitar o texto não necessariamente vai apertar enter para quebrar a linha.

```js
var $area = $(".textarea")

$area.keyup(function() {
  // HOW DETECT?
})
```

```css
textarea {
  background-color: aliceblue;
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="textarea">
</textarea>
```

Comment: Não consegui pensar em algo para detectar a quantidade de linhas independente da quebra (\n) mas talvez você pudesse controlar o aumento do tamanho verificando se o textarea tem um scroll. Se ele tiver um scroll maior que seu tamanho significa que você precisará aumentar uma linha. Seria algo assim: `if (el.scrollHeight > el.offsetHeight) { el.rows += 1; /* aqui podemos utilizar algum tipo de limite de tamanho */ }`. É só uma ideia, de repente te ajuda ;)

Comment: Pensei em fazer assim, o problema e se o usuario apagar, o scroll nao vai diminuir sozinho.

Answer (score 1):

Vinicius, eu vi uma solução para seu problema no seguinte link (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17772260/textarea-auto-height)

```js
autosize(document.getElementById("note"));
```

```css
textarea#note {
 width:100%;
 box-sizing:border-box; 
 display:block;
 max-width:100%;
 line-height:1.5;
 padding:15px 15px 30px;
 border-radius:3px;
 border:1px solid #F7E98D;
 font:13px Tahoma, cursive;
 transition:box-shadow 0.5s ease;
 box-shadow:0 4px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
 font-smoothing:subpixel-antialiased;
 background:linear-gradient(#F9EFAF, #F7E98D);
 background:-o-linear-gradient(#F9EFAF, #F7E98D);
 background:-ms-linear-gradient(#F9EFAF, #F7E98D);
 background:-moz-linear-gradient(#F9EFAF, #F7E98D);
 background:-webkit-linear-gradient(#F9EFAF, #F7E98D);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/jackmoore/autosize/master/dist/autosize.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="note">Texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto.</textarea>
```